# SMS with Mathematica not working

Tags: webservices

I am trying to send a message to my phone using the `SendMessage["SMS", "message"]` function when a lengthy piece of code finishes running. My number is linked to my account and `$MobilePhone` returns the correct number, but I keep getting the error:

> IntegratedServices`IntegratedServices::unexp: This service is currently not available. Please try again in a few minutes.

I've googled a bunch and can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: SendMessage requires internet connectivity, which I assume you checked, and it uses [4 Service Credits per message to send SMS](https://www.wolfram.com/service-credits/). Run `$ServiceCreditsAvailable` to check how many service credits you have.

Comment: I do have connectivity, yes. I didn't know about service credits (thank you for informing me!). I ran the command and it says I have 174, so that doesn't seem to be the immediate issue.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!